# Send to a publication list (excluding a data extension) without using Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, publicationlist

I'd like to send an email to all the subscribers of a Publication List `PL_1` Except the ones that are inside Data Extension `DE_1`.

I'd like to find a non-Automation-Studio solution for the customer. Is this possible?

Also, is it better to keep the excluded people inside a separate Data Extension or create a Suppression list for them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use User Initiated Email to send an email. Click on the edit recipients options. You will be taken to recipient page [image: you will be taken to recipient page] As you said you have a publication list you cannot directly use the publication list. You will have to create a DE and then select that DE in target recipient and then you will get an option to select the publication list 
[image]
then use DE_1 as you excluded recipients. Save the configuration and then click on send.

you can visit [Exclusion](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/exclusion_list/) or [Suppression](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/suppression_lists/) to know more about them.

Comment: that's exactly what i also wanted to do. but my publication lists do not appear in the recipient list for my user-initiated send. when you click on _My Lists_ do you see your publication lists there?

Comment: i have updated the answer above.

Comment: your answer is correct but can you help me with the logic here? why do we select a data extension and then select a publication list? will the data extension be populated with people inside that publication list? what happens to the columns inside the DE that are not in PL and vice versa?

Comment: The publication list is the source of truth, that is the subscriber key from the data extension will be compared with the publication list subscriber key, that is if your subscriber is opted out in publication list then that particular subscriber from DE will not receive an email. For more information, you can visit http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/publication_lists/